# How to keep and "debug" recursion function in my head?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging, recursion, computer-science

I have a question about recursion: how should I "think" to handle, keep and debug recursion in my head?
Let me explain: for example, we have a function that calculates Fibonacci number:

```
function fib(n) {
    if(n < 3) return 1;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

Looks very simple. Let's make it more simpler for debugging:

```
function fib(n) {
    if(n < 3) return 1;
    var r1 = fib(n - 1);
    var r2 = fib(n - 2);
    var result = r1 + r2;
    return result;
}
```

Now, let's see how this function will work, if n = 5:

```
fib(5) //n > 2, we need go deeper r1 = fib(n - 1) -> call fib(4)
    ->fib(4) //n > 2, we need go deeper r1 = fib(n - 1) -> call fib(3)
        ->fib(3) //n > 2, we need go deeper r1 = fib(n - 1) -> call fib(2)
            ->fib(2) n < 3 -> return 1
```

Now, let me write everything one more time (please, read from bottom to top, starting from fib(2)):

```
fib(5) n = 5; r1 = fib(4) -> 3; r2 = fib(3)//here we go one more time:
                                         r1 = fib(2) return [1]
                                         r2 = fib(1) return [1]
                                         r = r1 + r2 = 1 + 1 = [2]
                                         So fib(3) -> [2];
                                         Only now we can calculate fib(5):
                                            n = 5; r1 = 3; r2 = 2 ->
                                            r = r1 + r2 = 3 + 2 = 5; //Answer

    ->fib(4) n = 4; r1 = fib(3) -> 2; r2 = fib(2) -> 1; r = r1 + r2 = 2 + 1 = [3]
        ->fib(3) n = 3; r1 = fib(2) -> 1; r2 = fib(1) -> 1; r = r1 + r2 = 2 + 1 = [2] 
            ->fib(2) return [1]
```

And now let's see not recursion function for Fibonacci number:

```
function fn(number) {
    if(number === 0) return 0;
    var fib = [1, 1];

    for(var i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        var temp = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
        fib.push(temp);
    }
    return fib[fib.length - 1];
}
```

That function has a little bit more code, but it contains only one loop and I can easily keep everything in my head without that huge amount of recursive levels.

Recursive function that I show as an example is not mine, and I don't understand how should I think to implement functions like this. 
With loop everything is super easy:

1. we have an array with two values  arr = [1, 1].
2. We want to get next value?
3. No problem: just make sum for arr[n] = arr[n - 1] + arr[n -
   2]; return arr[n];

And that's it :)

Don't get me wrong, I spend several months to understand how to "parse" recursion functions in my head, but still didn't find any solution. Only using paper and thinking for hours works for me.

Comment: are you comfortable with stack and tree data structures? I am asking so that if you are comfortable, I can use that to better form my answer...

Comment: @TejashDesai, yes, I'm comfortable with trees and stack too

Comment: To compare your iterative solution to the recursive one you'd have to also write out the values for every iteration, which would give you roughly the same output volume albeit without the indentations.

Answer (score 2):

Visualize it!

```
function fib(n, indent) {
  console.log(indent + "fib(" + n + ")");
  if(n < 3) return 1;
  indent += "  ";
  return fib(n - 1, indent) + fib(n - 2, indent);
}
```

This modification will keep spaces corresponding to the recursion depth in the `indent` parameter and print them together with the call. Should help better seeing which call causes which other calls, and how the individual branches terminate.

Initial call:

```
 fib(4, "");
```

Note that in the simple recursive case, the runtime is exponential, whereas the iterative version is linear (try 20 or 30 to see the difference -- and you don't really need the array, just the last two values)

Comment: How did you manage to create that function? I'm trying to do that kind of outputs for almost year! How should I think? Sorry, I don't understand how to write such code. Could you explain, plase?

Comment: @NoNameYp Have expanded the answer to explain it better, and simplified the depth to an "indent" string. Don't get frustrated, it's mainly just a matter of working with code a lot (I have started about 33 years ago...)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that you’re trying to do too much in your head.

Recursive functions are declarative. In the case you provided, the nth Fibonacci is the sum of the (n-1) Fibonacci number and the (n-2) Fibonacci number. That’s it. That’s all your function says, and that’s the exact solution to the problem too: *NO THINKING REQUIRED*.

The *ONLY* thing you usually need to think about is the base case.

The trick? **Assume your function already works perfectly.** **Don’t think about how it’s working.** Just imagine it’s already there, working exactly how you need. You can pretend you didn’t even write this function - someone else wrote it, and it works.

The same method applies to almost any problem solved recursively.

Let’s say you want to get the minimum value in an array. Well, that’s the same as taking the first value out of the array and asking “is this value smaller than all other values?”

i.e.
In an array, [1,2,3,4,5], is the first element, 1, smaller than the smallest element in the rest of the array [2,3,4,5]?

We know we can get the minimum value in [2,3,4,5] because we are assuming our function works.

Just one thing left, what’s the base case?

If the array is empty, then a minimum value doesn’t make sense and we might need to either return a null-type value or raise an exception.

If the array has 1 element, then this must be the minimum value because there are no others. Great. So we have this:

```
function minimumValue(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        // handle this problem
    } else if (array.length == 1) {
        let firstElement = arr[0];
        return firstElement;
    }

    // assume the minimumValue function works
    let firstElement = arr[0];
    let restOfArray = arr.slice(1, arr.length);
    return min(firstElement, minimumValue(restOfArray));
}
```

I didn't need to think about much of anything. I just translated the exact solution I had in mind into code, and it works, and it's very readable IMO.

If you are into maths at all, then you can think of it like proof by induction. Assume it works up to N, and you just need to write the N+1 case. And of course, don’t forget the base case!

Edge cases and other problems are an inevitability, and sometimes it is useful to expand the recursive call a few times, or just carefully check that your programmed solution follows the actual solution you had in mind. Usually it is a matter of carefully considering the base cases.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is good, but could you provide please the complete code for that function? I'm not sure that I totally got the idea.

Comment: Done! If you are still struggling, let me know, because this function may not be the easiest to grasp due to the min() and 2 base cases. The core idea is wishful thinking. If you try to think too hard about the recursion it will be very difficult.

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot! One more question about min function: what it should do?

Comment: Return the minimum of the two numbers. min(1,5) == 1. min(5,3) == 3.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should think about your recursive function.

1. Answer: Should this be a recursive function? Do I have an iterative operation that I need to call until an terminating condition is met?
2. Answer: What is my terminating condition?
3. Answer: Do I need to check my terminating condition before I perform the operation or after?

From there you can form a more specific strategy based on your use case.

Comment: *Terminating condition* is also known as *base case*.

Answer (score 0):

I feel, simply stated, if you can do something with a `for` or `while` loop than you should. Don't go out of your way to to make it recursive if it doesn't need to be because they can get exponentially (literally) complicated and a pain in the butt do debug.

When you need to do something that requires recursion you'll know. You'll know cause you'll start with a `for` or `while` loop and after 2 days realize you can't do what you need and you're gonna need some sort of recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

When visualising how things work, I suggest you start with the edge case, and start working your way up (or down). If everything checks out for the first couple of inputs, things should work for "further" values.

Definitions in mathematics are often given recursively. Take a look at how fibonnaci sequence is defined:

```
f[0] = 0
f[1] = 1
f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2]
```

Try to imagine `n` being 2. What you get is

```
f[2] = f[1] + f[0] = 1 + 0 = 1
```

Now that you know what `f[2]` is, you don't have to rethink it when calculating `f[3]`. Just take the results you got in previous steps.

```
f[3] = f[2] + f[1] = (1 + 0) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
f[4] = f[3] + f[2] = 2 + 1 = 3
f[5] = f[4] + f[3] = 3 + 2 = 5
...
f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2]
```

Now let's convert this to JavaScript:

```
var fib = function(n){
  if( n === 0 || n === 1 )
    return n;
  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
};
```

As you can see, the function is very similar to the mathematical definition.
It would look even more so in a declarative language such as Haskell:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

I hearthily suggest you learn the basics of Haskell in order to get the grasp of recursion as it is used extensively. There is a very enjoyable tutorial [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) out there.

Even if you don't follow through, do read the [section on recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion).

Recursion may seem a bit convoluted at first, but after some practice, it will often be the simplest and most natural solution. That is especially true when dealing with structures that are recursive on their own, such as trees.

Some examples:

```
// get the sum of array
var sumArray = function( array ){
  if( array.length === 1 )                 // if only one element, it is the sum
    return array[0];
  return array.shift() + sumArray(array);  // return array[0] + sumArray(array.slice(1))
};
console.log( sumArray( [1,2,3] ) );


// recursive functions don't have to return a value
var repeatFunction = function( action, times ){
  if( times === 0 )
    return;
  action();
  repeatFunction( action, times-1 );
};
repeatFunction( function(){ alert('jah'); }, 3 );


// used in function below
var repeatString = function( string, times ){
  if( times < 1 )
    return '';
  return string + repeatString( string, times-1 );
};
console.log( repeatString( 'jah', 3 ) );


// and finally, a tree traversal
var readDOMStructure = function( element, level ){
  if( typeof level === 'undefined' )
    level = 0;
  else
    level++;
  console.log( repeatString( '  ', level ) + element.nodeName );
  for( var i=0, n=element.children.length; i<n; i++ )
    readDOMStructure( element.children[i], level );
};
readDOMStructure( document.getElementById( 'jah' ) );
```